# Join operation between Table and View

Tags: teradata

I have encountered with a problem while joining table with a view

```
select count(*) from table A inner join table B
on A.scen_id=B.scen_id
and A.value=10 --(till here records returned are 0)
inner join View C --this view contains millions of records
on B.scen_id=C.scen_id
```

Since join of two tables A and B returns 0 records but the whole query is takinh ~ 2 Hrs just because of View and gives me 0 records.

Is there any solution to this problem so i can get 0 records with a good performance?.

Comment: Are there statistics on the join columns? Can you show Explain?

Comment: And, of course on the `A.value` column?

Comment: When i ran command help stat on table, we are collecting stat on scen_id and not on A.value

Comment: Without stats on `A.value` the optimizer will estimate that the condition will return 10% of the rows, which is obviously totally wrong. With stats the order of joins will probably totally change.

Comment: I tried removing A.value filter and its taking a very long time again.The only option i can see is to turn the view to a table where i can define stats on joining column (C.scen_id)

Comment: If you remove the condtition on `A.value` you get a totally different answerset. Without more details like Explain & QryLogSteps it's impossible to help.

Comment: @denoeth : but my question is if first dataset (after joining table A and table B) returns 0 records then why teradata is joining it with view and waiting for 2 hours (when we are joining 0 recordset with a view or a table it should return 0 instantly)

Comment: When you check Explains you will notice that Teradata assumes that a large number of rows is returned by the first join and starting with the view is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following, send explain and lets know if it is working or not:

```
select count(*) 
from table A 
inner join table B
on A.scen_id=B.scen_id
inner join View C 
on B.scen_id=C.scen_id
where  A.value=10
```

also make sure stats on A.Value have been refreshed.